# Status of the "marker" keyword in Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I was looking though the [templating documentation for Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) and noticed that the example does not use the `marker` keyword in the base template, nor is it used later on in the documentation. However if you look [here](http://wsgiarea.pocoo.org/jinja/docs/inheritance.html), `marker` is used in the example with `block`.

Why is that? Is `marker` deprecated? Is one doc more up to date than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are documentation for two very different versions of Jinja.  http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/ documents the current version, Jinja2, while http://wsgiarea.pocoo.org/jinja/ documents an *old jinja "pre 1.0" version*, for historical purposes presumably.  `marker` was probably removed in Jinja2 because it is equivalent to an empty `block` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I liked the marker syntax better cause it seemed cleaner than an empty block; Makes sense to only have one pattern for it though.