# jinja: TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got 'string'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Have two files in a Flask application:

`base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    {% marker "content" %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`upload.html`, which extends `base.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block "content " %}
<title>Upload new File</title>
<h1>Upload new File</h1>
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <p><input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm calling the latter in a view: `return render_template('upload.html' )`, and I'm getting an error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got 'string'
```

Comment: {% block content %}? instead of "content", as it's a sort of identifier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `{% block "content" %}` should be `{% block content %}` - the block's name should not be quoted.

In addition the `marker` construct in your layout.html is [not a valid Jinja2 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685616/status-of-the-marker-keyword-in-jinja) - it should be `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`.